# Make custom "AdHoc Helper App" in the wake of UDID ban...?

Tags: ios, adhoc, udid

There are a lot of iOS apps in the iTunes Store that, upon launch, check the device's UDID and other info and setup a mail compose interface so your would-be beta testers can conveniently send you their UDIDs without all the iTunes hassle (e.g., can't copy/paste UDID in iTunes app, only in Xcode). For example, this one by Erica Sadun: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ad-hoc-helper/id285691333?mt=8

I am very aware that the UDID was deprecated some time ago and Apple has begun rejecting apps that use the deprecated API. But I would also like to make my own custom "Check your UDID and send it to me via e-mail" app, if anything because it looks more professional (and feels safer) than redirecting my potential beta testers to a third-party app made by someone else. 
(No offense to Erica!)

I guess what I want is not possible anymore...? Any thoughts, experiences to share?

*Also, I am not planning to use services like Test Flight at the moment (perhaps some day).

Comment: Btw, you can copy/paste the UDID out of iTunes: http://bjango.com/help/iphoneudid/

Comment: Wow, last time I checked (long time ago) you couln't even selct the text. Since when? Windows too?

Comment: It can't be selected again. Just click on the device on the left, make sure you're on `Summary` screen, click `Serial Number`, which will turn into UDID and then `Edit->Copy`..

Comment: Still, untethered UDID check would be great. Guess it's not possible anymore. I wonder if existing apps risk being kicked out of the store...

Comment: And if I dont have, use, or want iTunes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is apps that currently get the device identifier and use it somehow, won't be banned. The property `uniqueIdentifier` of `UIDevice` is depreciated in iOS5.0 so as long as you check you're on system with iOS5.0+ and don't use this property everything would be fine. What `Apple` suggest is

> **Special Considerations**
>  Do not use the *uniqueIdentifier* property. To create a unique identifier specific to your app, you can
>   call the *CFUUIDCreate* function to create a UUID, and write it to the
>   defaults database using the *NSUserDefaults* class.

Comment: I know. I also know about the 'app specific' UUID, but that won't work for provisioning profiles...